# Use C++ GMock matchers to test if an unordered_map's keys are from a set of keys

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

Lets say I have the following:

```
unordered_map<string, int> map{{"foo", 1}, {"bar", 2}, {"baz", 3}};
vector<string> expected_keys{"foo", "bar", "kaz"}; // Note "kaz" not "baz"
```

And I want to test that the keys from `map` are all contained in the set of `expected_keys`.

What I really want to write is this:

```
EXPECT_THAT(map, Each(Key(From(expected_keys))));
```

However, as far as I can tell, there's nothing that supports the `From` pattern; that is, checking that a value is from a set of values. The matcher library seems to assume that you'll always be doing `set contains value`, and never `value is in set`. In every case but this, these are equivalent. And, if `unordered_map` had a `keys()` API, you could fit it into the pattern using a simple `UnorderedElementsAreArray(expected_keys)`. But it doesn't.

The closest I could come up with was:

```
EXPECT_THAT(map, Each(Key(ResultOf([&](const key&){return Value(expected_keys, Contains(key));}, IsTrue())))
```

Which is... just terrible. `Pointwise()` is really close, but the orderedness of the search makes it not right for an unordered container.

Is there a way to do this kind of query directly without needing to resort to `ResultOf()` and `Value()`? Or am I thinking about the problem the wrong way?

Comment: As crutch you can use 'set_difference' and expect that result is empty.

Comment: It may be better to just write your own matcher for that, instead of chaining the built-it ones.

Comment: Gmock also has UnorderedPointwise. Does expected_keys need to be a vector? If not I think you could do something like EXPECT_THAT(map, UnorderedElementsAre(Key("foo"), Key("bar")...))

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
auto KeyMatch(const vector<string>& keys) {
  vector<decltype(Key(keys[0]))> matchers;
  for (const auto& val : keys) {
    matchers.push_back(Key(val));
  }
  return UnorderedElementsAreArray(matchers);
};

....
ASSERT_THAT(map, KeyMatch(keys));
```